# CPAN XML::DOM error installation - permission denied

Tags: xml, linux, xmldom

I am having problems to install the module XML::DOM on the server of the laboratory.
I have the following error when I type CPAN XML::DOM.

I cannot post  all the code because of the limitation of characters , so i paste the end of the result.

```
   TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.46.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 PERL_USE_UNSAFE_INC=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/build_dom.t ......... ok
t/dom_astress.t ....... ok
t/dom_attr.t .......... ok
t/dom_cdata.t ......... ok
t/dom_documenttype.t .. ok
t/dom_encode.t ........ ok
t/dom_example.t ....... ok
t/dom_extent.t ........ ok
t/dom_jp_astress.t .... ok
t/dom_jp_attr.t ....... ok
t/dom_jp_cdata.t ...... ok
t/dom_jp_example.t .... ok
t/dom_jp_minus.t ...... ok
t/dom_jp_modify.t ..... ok
t/dom_jp_print.t ...... ok
t/dom_minus.t ......... ok
t/dom_modify.t ........ ok
t/dom_noexpand.t ...... ok
t/dom_print.t ......... ok
t/dom_template.t ...... ok
t/dom_text.t .......... ok
All tests successful.
Files=21, Tests=129,  3 wallclock secs ( 0.08 usr  0.04 sys +  2.08 cusr  0.25 csys =  2.45 CPU)
Result: PASS
  TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.46.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Can't create '/usr/local/man/man3'
mkdir /usr/local/man/man3: Permission non accordée at /usr/share/perl/5.20/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 476.

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 at -e line 1.
Makefile:857: recipe for target 'pure_site_install' failed
make: *** [pure_site_install] Error 13
  TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.46.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- NOT OK
kelodjoe@hyperion:~$
```

Comment: Configure your cpan to use [local::lib](http://p3rl.org/local::lib).

Comment: You should `make` and `make check` as your regular user account. You should `make install` using root privileges, like `sudo make install`.

Comment: @choroba , i do not understand what you mean.

Comment: @jww I am trying to install on the server pf the laboratory and i do not have the rights of the administrator, i can only use pip .. --user to install module.

Comment: @kely789456123: Follow the link I gave you. It explains how to install Perl modules without admin privileges.